# WinJS does not show the autosuggestbox

Tags: javascript, typescript, winjs

I have a problem with WinJS. I don't get the problem. I want to fill (and I do it) the autosuggestbox with data-items. After that, normally, it has to show the autosuggestbox. But WinJS does not draw the list.

### HomeController:

```
    (function () {
    "use strict";
    WinJS.UI.Pages.define("/pages/home/home.html", {
        // This function is called whenever a user navigates to this page. It
        // populates the page elements with the app’s data.
        ready: function (element, options) {
            var searchBox1 = document.querySelector("#station1");
            var searchBox2 = document.querySelector("#station2");

            searchBox1.addEventListener("suggestionsrequested", GuiEvents.stationRequest);
            searchBox1.addEventListener("querysubmitted", Main.stationSubmittedHandler);

            searchBox2.addEventListener("suggestionsrequested", GuiEvents.stationRequest);
            searchBox2.addEventListener("querysubmitted", Main.stationSubmittedHandler);

            WinJS.UI.processAll();
        }
    });
})();
```

**The eventhandler:**

```
static stationRequest(event: CustomEvent) {
    var query = <string>event.detail.queryText;
    var suggestionCollection = event.detail.searchSuggestionCollection;
    var callback = function (response) {
        event.detail.setPromise(WinJS.Promise.then(null, function () {
            var _locations: Array<Object> = JSON.parse(response.responseText).LocationList.StopLocation;
            $("#response").text(JSON.stringify(_locations));
            _locations.forEach(function (obj: ILocation, index, _loc) {
                suggestionCollection.appendQuerySuggestion(obj.name);
            });

            event.detail.linguisticDetails.queryTextAlternatives.forEach(
                function (element, index, array) {
                    if (element.substr(0, query.length).toLocaleLowerCase() === query) {
                        suggestionCollection.appendQuerySuggestion(element);
                    }

                });
        }));
    };
    if (query.length > 3) {
        API.stationRequest(query, callback);
    }
}
```

I copied more or less the example form the windows WinJS site, but... It shows the responsetext very well to me in the `$("#response")`-element, but I get no box or list.

What is the failure.